# D3.Geo.Circle with Canvas

Tags: canvas, d3.js, geo

I'm using D3 to create a Mercator projection using a canvas rather than the SVG. I've got the path of the land working but I can't work out how to (if even possible) add d3.geo.circle at specific long/lat positions.

If it was SVG I'd use something like

```
var group = svg.append('g');
group.append('circle')
   .attr('cx', coords[0])
   .attr('cy', coords[1])
   .attr('r', 10)
   .style('fill', 'red');
```

But I can't work out how to translate that to a canvas and I'm not finding much in the way of resources for D3 using the canvas rather than SVG.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to create it manually using the canvas `arc` command:

```
var coords = [50, 50];
var r = 10;

ctx.beginPath();
// Make an arc from 0 to Math.PI*2, aka a full circle
ctx.arc(coords[0], coords[1], r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/9kmV3/

---

Edit: It appears you mean expressing latitude and longitude with an appropriate transformation on the canvas, have a look at this instead:

```
var coords = [47.61, -122.33];
var r = 5;

ctx.beginPath();
// Make an arc from 0 to Math.PI*2, aka a full circle

// X = Longitude
// Y = Latitude
// Negative latitude values go upwards, so we reverse the sign of latitude

ctx.arc(coords[1], -coords[0], r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
```

Live example placing Seattle on a map: http://jsfiddle.net/9kmV3/1/

Comment: Thanks Simon. I'd managed to get the arc on the canvas but I think D3 must do something different with the coordinates more to translate them to pixel.

For example, Seattle is [47.61,-122.33] so there must be something in the (cx, cy) attribute that can do the translation. Thats the bit I'm missing

Comment: Oh. You're not given litearal X and Y coordinates. You're given latitude and longitude. I've edited my answer with an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

here's a snippet of code I am working on at the moment:

```
    var circle = d3.geo.circle().angle(circleSize()).origin([0, 52]);
    circles = [circle()];
    context.beginPath();
    path({type: "GeometryCollection", geometries: circles});
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,100,0,.5)";
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = .2;
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.stroke();
```

this draws a circle and projects it onto the canvas. I.e. if you're using orthographic projection it will appear in perspective.